# Java regex using Pattern and Matcher

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use matcher as an expression to find time stamps in my list of strings. Ex (" [00:00:00.000] ") There are white spaces before and after the time stamp

I checked my regex online and it say it is correct but will not work with my java. It just returns false.

```
String word = " [00:00:00.000] ";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s[[0-9:.]*]\\s");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
    if(matcher.matches()){
        //Do Stuff
    else
        //Do other Stuff
```

Comment: OK.. please be clear.. Do you want to extract the timestamp or just check if your string contains a timestamp?

Comment: you simply need to escape the first `[` like `\[` and the last `]` like `\]`. The reason is that the angle brackets are a special character in regular expressions. So the regex checker is wrong. So, I think this would also have caused issues in other programming languages. (Note, in java you will need to escape twice, (`\\[` and `\\]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\\s*\\[[0-9:.]*\\]\\s*
```

Use this.You dont need `^`.`escape` `[]`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eX9gK2/11

If you want timestamps use

```
\\s*\\[([0-9:.]*)\\]\\s*
```

and capture the `group 1`

Comment: The OP says *to find timestamps*. This *matches* timestamps :)

Comment: Well in that case `\\[\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}\\]` would have been the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
^\\s\\[[0-9:.]*]\\s
```

You regex doesn't work because you did't escape first `[` character, so it is treated as another character class. You can get timestamp by closing it into group: `([0-9:.]*)`, but also, if your timestamp always look like this, you can get separate time values with:

```
^\\s\\[(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)*]\\s
```

it will give you:

- hrs - group(1),
- min - group(2),
- sec - group(3),
- msec - group(4),

test it in Java:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String word = " [00:00:00.000] ";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s\\[(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)*]\\s");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + ":" + matcher.group(2) + ":"  + matcher.group(3) + "." + matcher.group(4));
}
```

Comment: The second `]` also needs escaping.

Comment: @MattBall in Java it is not necessary, it will work, I tested it

Comment: @EsotericRider which one?

Answer (score 0):

```
package test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;

public class RegexTest {

    @Test
    public void assert_pattern_found() {
        final String word = " [00:00:00.000] ";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s\\[[0-9:.]*\\]\\s");
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);

        assertTrue(matcher.matches());
    }

}
```